# when login user in laravel form tries to register

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

When I submit my user credentials instead of lining in form tries to register me as new user.

here is my controller:

```
public function postCreate() {
    $input = Input::all();

    $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);

    if ($validation->passes()) {
        $user = new User;
        $user->username = Input::get('username');
        $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
        $user->save();

        return Redirect::route('home')->with('message', 'Thanks for      registering');
    } else {
        return Redirect::route('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
    }
}

public function getLogin() {
    return View::make('users.login')->with('title', 'Project - Login');
}

public function postLogin()
{
    $user = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

    $validator = Validator::make($user, User::$rules);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
            return Redirect::to('home');
        }
        else 
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
    }

    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

and route :

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showIndex'));
Route::get('register', array('as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getNew'));
Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@getLogin'));

Route::post('register', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postCreate'));
Route::post('login', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'UsersController@postLogin'));
```

Error when I attempt login : 
The username has already been taken.
The password confirmation does not match.

I have used this code before and it worked, but what is the problem now, I don't know.

Comment: Can you share your $rules array please?

Comment: public static $rules = array (
  'username' => 'Required|Unique:users|AlphaDash|Min:4',
  'password' => 'Required|AlphaNum|confirmed',
  'password_confirmation' => 'Required|AlphaNum'
 );

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to confirm password for the login $rules array.

```
$rules = array(
    'username'  => 'required|email|exists:users',
    'password'  => 'required',
);
```

This should work for the postLogin validation rules.